# Getting Object After submitting a form in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is form where we ahve 2 select fields , First select field is the Node / Vertex for example "T1" , now we are selecting all the edges where T1 is connected, from a drop down list ..Example  T1 is connected to T2 , T3 and so on . Now we need to get the below grouped object from the that Node with the Weight / Distance .

```
                <form>
                   <select id="selectFromPOI" >
                      <option>Choose a POI to Start From</option>
                      <option value="T1">T1</option>
                      <option value="T2">T2</option>
                      <option value="T3">T3</option>
                      <option value="T4">T4</option>
                      <option value="CP C1">CP C1</option>
                      <option value="CP C2">CP C2</option>
                      <option value="CP C3">CP C3</option>
                      <option value="CP C4">CP C4</option>
                      <option value="CP C5">CP C5</option>
                      <option value="CP C6">CP C6</option>
                      <option value="CP C7">CP C7</option>
                      <option value="CP C8">CP C8</option>
                      <option value="CP C9">CP C9</option>
                      <option value="CP C10">CP C10</option>
                      <option value="CP C11">CP C11</option>
                   </select>
                   <select id="selectToPOI" multiple="">
                      <option value="T1">T1 , distance 0</option>
                      <option value="T2">T2 , distance 42</option>
                      <option value="T3">T3 , distance 88</option>
                      <option value="T4">T4 , distance 129</option>
                      <option value="CP C1">CP C1 , distance 60</option>
                      <option value="CP C2">CP C2 , distance 263</option>
                      <option value="CP C3">CP C3 , distance 273</option>
                      <option value="CP C4">CP C4 , distance 289</option>
                      <option value="CP C5">CP C5 , distance 293</option>
                      <option value="CP C6">CP C6 , distance 385</option>
                      <option value="CP C7">CP C7 , distance 366</option>
                      <option value="CP C8">CP C8 , distance 326</option>
                      <option value="CP C9">CP C9 , distance 294</option>
                      <option value="CP C10">CP C10 , distance 303</option>
                      <option value="CP C11">CP C11 , distance 302</option>
                   </select></form>
```

IF i select T2 i can choose multiple options , below is the expected object

```
        graph = {
            T2: { T3: 46, T4: 87 },
            T4: { T2: 87 , T3 : 41}
        };
```

This is what i am trying but not getting expected result .

```
        function selectPOIs(){
            // gettig the first element 
            var edge =  document.getElementById("selectFromPOI").value;
            // getting all the selected elements  as an array 
            var edgePaths = document.querySelectorAll('#selectToPOI option:checked');
            var text = "";
            var graph = {}; 
            edgePaths.forEach(
                function(node, index) {
                    item = {} ; 
                    item[edge] =  node.text ; 
                    graph[edge][node] = item ; // something like this so that i can get the above object 
                }
              );
        
              console.log('>>>' +JSON.stringify(graph));


        }
```

Comment: `graph[edge][node] = item` is weird, given `node` appears to have properties due to the preceding line `item[edge] =  node.text`

Comment: It looks like there something missing. Like how does T3 = 41 in one object and 46 in another? That entire object's values aren't showing anywhere.

Comment: it was just a sample , edgePaths.forEach function is what need to be  checked .T3 is at distance 41 from point T4 but at 46 from point T1